# Magento 2 - Remove Size guide & Delivery & Return option from product page

Tags: magento2

How can I remove Size guide & Delivery & Return option from product page, please check the screenshow below.

[image]

I also check the file code,

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */ ?>

<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data'); ?>

<?php if($_product->getMgsDetailTemplate() == ""): ?>
    <?php $templateLayout = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/product_ct_template'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php $templateLayout = $_product->getMgsDetailTemplate(); ?>
<?php endif ?>

<?php $galleryPopup = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/popup_gallery'); ?>
<?php $stickyMenu = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/general/sticky_menu'); ?>
<?php $cr_header = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/general/header'); ?>
<?php $class = "product-detail-media"; ?>

<?php if(!$templateLayout): ?><?php $templateLayout = 0; ?><?php endif ?>
<input id="mgs_template_layout" type="hidden" name="mgs_template_layout" value="<?php echo $templateLayout; ?>">
<input id="galleryPopup" type="hidden" name="galleryPopup" value="<?php echo $galleryPopup; ?>">
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.popup.gallery') ?>

<?php if ($priceAmount = $_product->getFinalPrice()):?>
    <div class="no-display price product-price"><?php echo $priceAmount; ?></div>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if($templateLayout != 5): ?>
    <?php if($templateLayout == 3): ?>
        <?php //Product with sticky info 2  ?>
        <div class="row sticky-info-multiple-col">
            <div class="col-lg-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs product-detail-infomation  product-detail-infomation-sticky">
                <div class="product-detail-infomation-content <?php if($stickyMenu && $cr_header): ?> has-sticky-menu<?php endif ?>">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
                    <div class="product-info-main">
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.name') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.review') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.price') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.price.tier') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.overview') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.main') ?>
                        <div class="product-sub-infomation">
                            <div class="product-info-stock-sku">
                                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.type') ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.sku') ?>
                            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.brand.name') ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12<?php if($galleryPopup): ?> product-gallery-popup<?php endif ?>">
                <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.media.image') ?>
                </div>      
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-detail-infomation  product-detail-infomation-sticky">
                <div class="product-info-main <?php if($stickyMenu && $cr_header != 'header_5'): ?> has-sticky-menu<?php endif ?>">
                    <div class="hidden-lg">
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.name') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.review') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.price') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.price.tier') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.overview') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.main') ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('bundle.options.container') ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info') ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('custom.product.detail.top.static.block') ?>

                    <div class="product-sub-infomation hidden-lg">
                        <div class="product-info-stock-sku">
                            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.type') ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.sku') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.brand.name') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/share_config/share_product_detail')): ?>
                        <div class="text-center margin-top20">
                            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.detail.sharethis') ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            'jquery',
            'sticky-content'
            ], function($){
                $(window).scroll(function(){
                    $(".product-detail-infomation-sticky").stick_in_parent({
                        parent: $('.sticky-info-multiple-col')
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="row product-detail-infomation-sticky-parent">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12<?php if($galleryPopup): ?> product-gallery-popup<?php endif ?>">
                <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.media.image') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-detail-infomation product-detail-infomation-sticky">
                <div class="product-detail-infomation-content<?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/general/sticky_menu') && $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/general/header') != 'header_5'): ?> has-sticky-menu<?php endif ?>">
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
                    <div class="product-info-main">
                        <?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>
                        <div class="kwc-pro-head">
                            <h1 class="product-name"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getName(), 'name') ?></h1></div>

                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.name') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.review') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.price') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.price.tier') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.overview') ?>

                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.main') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('bundle.options.container') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info') ?>
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('custom.product.detail.top.static.block') ?>

                        <div class="product-sub-infomation">
                            <div class="product-info-stock-sku">
                                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.type') ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.sku') ?>
                            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.brand.name') ?>

                            <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/share_config/share_product_detail')): ?>
                                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.detail.sharethis') ?>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </div>

                        <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('protabs/general/position')): ?>
                            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.details') ?>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if(!$themeHelper->getStoreConfig('protabs/general/position') || $templateLayout== 3): ?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.details') ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if($templateLayout == 2): ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            'jquery',
            'sticky-content'
            ], function(jQuery){
                (function($) {
                    $(window).scroll(function(){
                        $(".product-detail-infomation-sticky").stick_in_parent({
                            parent: $('.product-detail-infomation-sticky-parent')
                        });
                    });
                })(jQuery);
            });
        </script>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else:?>
    <div class="row product-detail-infomation-slide-gallery">
        <div id="slide-gallery" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.media.image') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="product-detail-infomation-content<?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/general/sticky_menu') && $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/general/header') != 'header_5'): ?> has-sticky-menu<?php endif ?>">
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
            <div class="product-info-main">
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.name') ?>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.review') ?>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.price') ?>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.price.tier') ?>

                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.main') ?>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('bundle.options.container') ?>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info') ?>
                <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/share_config/share_product_detail')): ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.detail.sharethis') ?>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('custom.product.detail.top.static.block') ?>
                <div class="product-sub-infomation">
                    <div class="product-info-stock-sku">
                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.type') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.sku') ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.brand.name') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.overview') ?>

                <?php if($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('protabs/general/position')): ?>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.details') ?>
                <?php endif ?>

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.details') ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
            'jquery'
            ], function(jQuery){
                (function($) {
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#slide-gallery').insertAfter('.breadcrumbs');
                    });
                })(jQuery);
            });
        </script>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
    'jquery'
    ], function(jQuery){
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.product-info-main .product-reviews-summary a').click(function(event){
                    event.returnValue = false;
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(".product.info.detailed").offset().top - 150
                    }, 300);
                    <?php if(!$themeHelper->getStoreConfig('protabs/general/type')): ?>
                    if($(window).width() > 767){
                        $('#tab-label-reviews-title').click();
                    }else {
                        $('.title-accordion.accordion-reviews').click();
                    }
                    <?php else: ?>
                    if(!$('.title-accordion.accordion-reviews').hasClass('active')){
                        $('.title-accordion.accordion-reviews').click();
                    }
                    <?php endif ?>
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your code. And you have to use xml file for remove it. You have to find block name and write like this : <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />

Comment: @chirag Parmar, I tried searching the block name but cant find it...